# Is it possible to prevent unordered_map::insert from throwing exceptions?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, std, unordered-set

I'd like to prevent std::unordered_set::insert() from throwing exceptions. Does std::unordered_set::reserve() serve that purpose if I reserved the max number of elements I would ever insert into the unordered_set?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Also, `unordered_map` or `unordered_set`?

Comment: To prevent it from throwing exceptions than you need to write perfect code.  Exceptions are there for important reasons (some that may be beyond your control) and you need to handle them.  If you are trying to insert an item into a set and the insert fails, you should find out why it fails.  If you *really* want to prevent exceptions, then you will need to test every possible scenario you can think of and handle them gracefully in your code.  Even then, you just have to hope nothing goes wrong elsewhere in your program or on the user's system.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately reserve() can only be used to control when there will be a rehash, so iterators will stay valid at least until the reserved number of elements has been inserted. An insert can still throw bad_alloc (with the default allocator) while within the reserved range.

For the nothrow guarantee the only possibility would be to know beforehand what keys could be inserted, then insert them all at a point where an exception could be easily handled.